# Print the value of a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, keras

The following is the link to my full code:

https://github.com/roshanDD/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L253

I just wanna print out the value of the tensor, called `true_areas`. I ran my code:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]
tf.Print(true_areas, [true_areas], message = "This is True Areas: ")
b = tf.add(true_areas, true_areas).eval()
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Caused by op 'input_2', defined at:
  File "learning.py", line 358, in <module>
    _main(args)
  File "learning.py", line 66, in _main
    model_body, model = create_model(anchors, class_names)
  File "learning.py", line 185, in create_model
    boxes_input = Input(shape=(None, 5))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1388, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1299, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 349, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_2' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

What is that placeholder it's talking about?

Comment: can you please add the full code? the stacktrace does not match anything you've supplied in terms of code. (all of learning.py would be a good start)

Comment: https://github.com/roshanDD/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L253

Comment: Learning.py is here: https://github.com/roshanDD/YAD2K/blob/master/learning.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages tells you, that somewhere in your code you defined a [tf.placeholder()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) called `input_2`.

You need to [feed](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#feeding) values to this placeholder when you want to evaluate a graph that depends on this placeholder. It should look something like this:

```
b = tf.add(true_areas, true_areas).eval({input_2: someInputValues})
```

Comment: Is it possible not to feed it onto `input_2` and just print out the value of the tensor?

Comment: I mean, I just want to see the value of the tensor. I dont want to change the value of any other variables. Can I define a new place holder or something?

Comment: Doesn't the value of this tensor depend on the values in this input-tensor? If yes, you need to provide the input tensor. Otherwise tensorflow cannot compute the values. And it would be very helpful, if you can provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `true_wh` has some values. Where do these values come from?

Comment: @ sietschie
https://github.com/roshanDD/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L253

Comment: So you set up a graph and while you are setting it up, you want to know the contants of some tensor? What do you want to achieve? At this point it does not contain anything. Something needs to be computed first. And this is what `eval()` tries to do. But to do this, it needs the inputs, which are missing. But my guess is you want to do something else: Not print the tensor while building the graph, but later, when you run it?